# How is it possible to efficiently implement a reverse proxy in a PHP?

Tags: php, apache, sockets, nginx, fastcgi

I want to reverse proxy a file download in PHP.

Example: http://my-server-1/download.php?url=http://my-server-2/file.bin

The PHP script on server 1 fetches the file from server 2 and delivers it to the user.

It is a little more complicated because the request data such as URL, Cookies, Referer etc is passed in an encrypted blog that the PHP script  decrypts and uses for the outgoing request.

I am aware that there are "better" solutions for this, such as nginx reverse proxying, that also offer the flexibility I want. But unfortunately they are not really suitable in this case. I would prefer to implement it in PHP.

I know that this is trivial to implement, but I am concerned about the efficiency and load on the server.

There will be many simultaneous downloads and a log of bandwidth will be used. The files delivered will usually be big media files such as Videos etc.

I considered the following options:

1. Build my own socket server in PHP and do not use a webserver software at all. This would probably be the most efficient since data does not need to be sent over a FastCGI socket or something like that.
2. Run the PHP script via FastCGI and NGINX. I would probably need a huge pool of workers, because the requests take a long time to complete. This is not really the scenario FastCGI usually seems to be used in, but I don't know whether there are any inherent problems
3. Use Apache2 with the built in mod_php module. This would elimiate the need for passing the data through the FastCGI interface.

I have bad experiences with Apache2 in high-load environments in general, but in the specific situation I am inclined to believe that Apache2 would actually be the best choice, apart from implementing the socket server in PHP which I want to avoid if possible.

Which solution would be the best and why? Is there another way?

Also: What other things have to be considered? Output buffering, etc.

It also seems that the perfect choice for this would be node.js with the socket.io library. But due to my lack of experience with node.js I would like to find another way.

Comment: Do you actually **need** to serve the files from your server? Do you control the final download location? What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: php is so far from the right tool for the job. I wouldn't consider any of 3 options as something robust enough for production use.

Comment: Yes, I need to deliver from that server. It is going to be a CDN network.

Comment: Have you considered using [`X-Accel-Redirect`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) and let `nginx` deliver the content after PHP does its bit?

Comment: @TheSurrican as far as I know CDN doesn't work this way, you'll need storage nodes and a balancer that redirects the user properly, there's no php involved.

Comment: @RichardSmith As far as I know this module does not support external URIs. Furthermore it does not support custom request headers such as cookies, range requests etc.

Comment: @RichardSmith What you are describing is a CDN where you actively store your content on the edge servers. Usually CDNs  dynamically fetch it from the origin when it is first requested. This usually involves a backend configuration (where you manually define the origin server in the config), which I don't want to do.

Comment: Have you considered Nginx `auth_request` with PHP and `proxy_pass` after validation?

Comment: @TanHongTat that is a great suggestion and almost viable. sadly i cannot pass the url in encrypted form, only authorize it. anyway i opted for the option to pass request parameters to a script via an nginx lua script and from there set the variables necessary for proxy pass